# Utilizar valores de um dicionário que está dentro de uma lista

Tags: python, lista, dicionário

Basicamente, eu estou fazendo um trabalho escolar e por isso sou limitado a certas condições, uma foi criar uma lista que recebe cadastros em forma de dicionário, então operar esses dados dentro da lista:

Uma das atividades é executar a média das notas dos alunos e por isso eu criei essa função, só que ela não recebe os valores do dicionário para que possam ser operados em uma nova lista

```
def nota_media(alunos):
    notas = list()
    for i in alunos: 
        notas = alunos[i]['nota']
    return sum[notas]/len(notas)

alunos = [{'name': 'Naruto', 'sexo': 'M', 'nota': '5.0'}, {'name': 'Sakura ', 'sexo': 'F', 'nota': '10.0'}]

nota_media(alunos)
```

Aparece isso aqui:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    nota_media(alunos)
  File "main.py", line 5, in nota_media
    notas = float(alunos[i]['nota'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Entretanto, se eu chamo algo como:`

```
alunos = [{'name': 'Naruto', 'sexo': 'M', 'nota': '5.0'}, {'name': 'Sakura ', 'sexo': 'F', 'nota': '10.0'}]

print(alunos[0]['nota'])
```

Retorna o valor corretamente de
`5.0`

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de receber esses valores ou de chamar esses valores apenas para uma lista, para que eles possam ser trabalhados de forma individual.

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se você tem limitações de uso de bibliotecas. Em todo caso, o método mais fácil seria:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

alunos = [{'name': 'Naruto', 'sexo': 'M', 'nota': '5.0'}, {'name': 'Sakura ', 'sexo': 'F', 'nota': '10.0'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(alunos)

df["nota"] = df["nota"].astype("float32")

np.mean(df["nota"]) #7.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma possibilidade e resolvi compartilhar, já que talvez ajude alguém mais tarde.

Basicamente seleciona apenas os elementos de 'nota' do dicionário, entretanto, como os valores estão em str, ainda é necessário converter para float

```
def nota_media(alunos):
    x = list(map(lambda x : x['nota'], alunos))
    notas = []
    for i in x:
      notas.append(float(i))
    return print(sum(notas)/len(notas)) 

alunos = [{'name': 'Naruto', 'sexo': 'M', 'nota': '5.0'}, {'name': 'Sakura ', 'sexo': 'F', 'nota': '10.0'}

nota_media(alunos) #7.5
```

Se os valores já forem em float fica bem mais simples:

```
def nota_media(alunos):
    notas = list(map(lambda x : x['nota'], alunos))
    return print(sum(notas)/len(notas))
  
alunos = [{'name': 'Naruto', 'sexo': 'M', 'nota': 5.0}, {'name': 'Sakura ', 'sexo': 'F', 'nota': 10.0}]

nota_media(alunos) #7.5
```

Comment: Não precisa criar uma lista só de notas, pode fazer um loop simples e ir somando: https://ideone.com/tFTuK8 - repare também que mudei a função para somente retornar o valor (vc está fazendo `return print`, o que não faz sentido: ou imprime ou retorna, mas em geral para funções faz mais sentido retornar)

Comment: Ahhh, assim fica bem mais facil de compreender e de aplicar, valeu.